# Django - cache queryset for object_list

Tags: django, django-queryset, objectlistview

I'm using an object_list() method manually in one of my views for pagination and some other cool autmation stuff. I try to cache huge queryset and take care of everything what can influence object_list (eg. request.GET['page']) but simpled idea looks like:

```
def some_view(request):
qs = cache.get('key')
if qs == None:
    qs = QS.objects.filter(some_huge_query)
    cache.set('key', qs)
return object_list(queryset = qs,...)
```

Actually queryset is executed once again during template rendering. Is there any way to prevent queryset from being executed?

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
if qs = None:
```

is the problem. You're storing `None` in `qs` instead of checking equality (`==`). As a result, `qs` is *always* `None`, and gets r-evaluated each time through.

You need to change it to:

```
if qs == None:
```

Or, just simply:

```
if not qs:
```

Comment: Sorry, of course it was comparision, not assigment. I made a mistake in this example.

Comment: Does: qs = cache.get('key') not also set qs = None if that key doesn't exist? If it's not explicitly set using .get('key', None), what would qs equal if that key didn't exist?

Comment: It would equal None. I've tested it many times and I'm sure that cache works just fine and the problem is on the Django's side.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that the question's sample code had been updated.

Comment: If your answer is "it's something wrong on Django's side", you're most likely wrong. Instances of that are relatively rare and when they exist, they are well documented by the community.

Comment: Never, ever compare something this way: `qs == None` or `qs != None`. The proper way (according to a PEP whose number I forgot) is `qs is None` or `qs is not None`.

Comment: I wasn't condoning the style; I was illustrating where the OP went wrong (trying to compare equality with one equal sign instead of two).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to turn that huge QuerySet into a list and then hand that list to the template, which should cause the QuerySet to be re-evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the evaluated queryset in your cache, so you should call:

```
cache.set('key', list(qs))
```

to force the queryset be evaluated to a list; otherwise it will be merely the query being stored in the cache!

Comment: It won't work. object_list expects a querysets, not a list so it fails ('list' object has no attribute '_clone').

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know:

```
if qs == None:
```

might evaluate your queryset. At least I'm pretty sure that `if qs` or `if not qs` evaluates the queryset.

Try:

```
if qs is not None:
```

Also it would be useful to see your `object_list` method and template.